# Is it possible to connect a microphone to an iPhone/iPad via WiFi and use it instead of the built in one?

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, bluetooth, microphone

It is possible to connect a microphone to an iPhone/iPad using bluetooth, BUT would it be possible to achieve the same kind of connection with a microphone but over a WiFi network?

To explain: I have a microphone that is connected to an router via WiFi, would it be possible in some way to connect the iPhone/iPad to this microphone and use it instead of the built in microphone?

Comment: Confusing question - you first ask about Bluetooth, but then say the mic is connected via WiFi.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Not so confusing after all; I state that I know it is possible to connect a mic with Bluetooth and ask if there is some API or other way to connect a mic with WiFi.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-read. I am getting old!

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer No problem :) You don't happen to have any insight in this though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is possible to do it through bluetooth, dock connector, and 3.5mm headphone jack!

in order to use it though wifi you need a compatible application and i have never heard of such thing! after a little goggling all i found was bluetooth connected ones, because it offers a P2P connection witch is much more reliable!

(sidenote) mics though wifi routers **could**, be unreliable, specially in poor connection!

however there are mic's that include a dock connector dongle for a stable P2P connection 
something like [this](http://store.apple.com/us/product/H7604LL/A/soulo-digital-wireless-mic-karaoke-app)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an app like Facetime or Skype to create a streaming link between your iPad and another network-connected device (smart phone, iPad, iPod, computer). This would allow the remote device to serve as the "microphone" that would serve as audio input to your iPad and allow you to monitor and/or record the audio from the remote device.